# Ruby on Rails CanCan Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

I am a bit confused regarding CanCan Gem. I basically understand how to set up abillity.rb. For example lest say we have the following code:

```
// in abillity.rb

user ||= User.new

can [:update, :destroy, :edit, :read], Book do |book|
  book.dashboard.user_id == user.id
end
```

And then lets say we have the following books controller:

```
// books_controller.rb
load_and_authorize_resource

def destroy
  if can?(:destroy, @book)
    @book.destroy!
    redirect_to happy_world_path
  else
    redirect_to not_happy
  end
end
```

My question is: Do we need to check 'can?(:destroy, @book)'? 
From my understanding 'load_and_authorize_resource' will not even allow access to this method if we don't have abillity to destroy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo do not need to add `if can?(:destroy, @book)` in your action if you use `load_and_authorize_resource`

Like the [README](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization) say

> Setting this for every action can be tedious, therefore the load_and_authorize_resource method is provided to automatically authorize all actions in a RESTful style resource controller.

If an user without authorization try to destroy, he get a unauthorized response ( not remember if is a 401 code)

Maybe you can use `if can?(:destroy, @book)` in your views, to do no show thte destroy button. Like also in [Check Abilities & Authorization](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization) section